# UWP, Apply a converter to a ListView's item when the ListView's items source is a collection of strings

Tags: string, listview, uwp, converters

I have the following situation. I want to show a list of strings. In order to achieve that, I have a ListView bound to a collection of strings. In this collection, there are some empty strings. What I want is to show the following text when a empty string is present: "-empty-". This is what I got so far (the source code is for demonstration purpose only):

EmptyStringConverter.cs

```
public class EmptyStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is string && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)value))
        {
            return "-empty-";
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
        x:Class="App1.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:App1"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <local:EmptyStringConverter x:Key="EmptyStringConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <ListView x:Name="ListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EmptyStringConverter}}" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var source = new[] { "", "String 1", "String 2" };
        ListView.ItemsSource = source;
    }
}
```

When a put a breakpoint in the Convert method in EmptyStringConverter class, the method is called in every single item except in the empty string. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the issue was in the place I'd check the last. It's your `Legacy Binding` that's causing the issue. I tried a code snippet myself and then I replaced it with yours piece by piece. The below line uses `legacy binding`

`Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EmptyStringConverter}}"`

Since you are using `UWP` you can switch to a `Compile time binding` that'll fix your problem your modified `ListView` `XAML` would be:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource EmptyStringConverter},Mode=OneTime}" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Please pay attention at two things:

1. the `Text` section of the `Textbox` in the `DataTemplate`, it uses `x:Bind` instead of `Binding`. Please do note that compile time binding is a `oneTime` binding by default (unless you explicitly mention the Mode) where as the Legacy `Binding` is a `OneWay` binding by default. For More information on compile time binding follow: [xBind markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension).
2. If you notice the `DataTemplate` declaration holds a `DataType` property, that helps the compile time binder to know what kind of data is it expecting. For more information on `DataType` follow: [xBind markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension).

---

All that being said, I would highly recommend using the `Data Binding` approach instead of the `ListView.ItemSource=source` as with the new Compile Time binding, alot of conversions are handled by the binding engine itself leading to less code and effort on your end. I've put up a sample on github for the same you can check it out: [EmptyStringDemo](https://github.com/ImCarrot/EmptyStringDemoStack)